# What would cause a mysql query based on month() and year() to be faster than querying against its numeric equivalent directly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-python

I am attempting to speed up a SQL query in MySql 5.7 by replacing YEAR() and MONTH() functions with their numeric equivalents during insert time. Specifically, I added the columns reportMonth, reportYear, both bigint(20) for that.

Interestingly, that approach is much slower. Why is that so? Shouldn't it be faster to run a query with fewer functions in it?

**This takes about 12 seconds to complete. (with YEAR() and MONTH() functions)**

```
SELECT 
   ProductTitle AS 'ProductTitle',  
   YEAR(ReportPeriodEndDay) AS 'Year',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 1  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Jan',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 2  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Feb',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 3  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Mar',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 4  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Apr',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 5  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'May',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 6  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Jun',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 7  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Jul',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 8  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Aug',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 9  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Sep',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 10 THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Oct',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 11 THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Nov',
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportPeriodEndDay) = 12 THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Dec',
   SUM(OrderedRevenue) AS 'TOTAL'
 FROM 
   `sales_diagnostic_summary_orderedrevenuelevel`
 GROUP BY ProductTitle, Year
 WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Result from EXPLAIN**

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, sales_diagnostic_summary_orderedrevenuelevel, , ALL, , , , , 745140, 100.00, Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**This takes more than 120 seconds (with numeric equivalents)**

```
SELECT 
   ProductTitle AS 'ProductTitle',  
   reportYear AS 'Year',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 1  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Jan',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 2  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Feb',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 3  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Mar',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 4  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Apr',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 5  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'May',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 6  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Jun',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 7  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Jul',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 8  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Aug',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 9  THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Sep',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 10 THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Oct',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 11 THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Nov',
   SUM(CASE WHEN reportMonth = 12 THEN OrderedRevenue END) AS 'Dec',
   SUM(OrderedRevenue) AS 'TOTAL'
 FROM 
   `sales_diagnostic_summary_orderedrevenuelevel`
 GROUP BY ProductTitle, Year
 WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Result from EXPLAIN**

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, sales_diagnostic_summary_orderedrevenuelevel, , ALL, , , , , 745140, 100.00, Using filesort
```

**Table mapping via DESCRIBE**

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
ASIN, text, YES, MUL, , 
ProductTitle, text, YES, , , 
OrderedRevenue, double, YES, , , 
OrderedRevenuePercentOfTotal, double, YES, , , 
OrderedRevenuePriorPeriod, double, YES, , , 
OrderedRevenueLastYear, double, YES, , , 
OrderedUnits, double, YES, , , 
OrderedUnitsPercentOfTotal, double, YES, , , 
OrderedUnitsPriorPeriod, double, YES, , , 
OrderedUnitsLastYear, double, YES, , , 
SubcategorySalesRank, bigint(20), YES, , , 
SubcategoryBetterWorse, double, YES, , , 
AverageSalesPrice, double, YES, , , 
AverageSalesPricePriorPeriod, double, YES, , , 
ChangeInGVPriorPeriod, double, YES, , , 
ChangeInGVLastYear, double, YES, , , 
RepOOS, double, YES, , , 
RepOOSPercentOfTotal, double, YES, , , 
RepOOSPriorPeriod, double, YES, , , 
LBBPrice, double, YES, , , 
ReportPeriodStartDay, datetime, YES, , , 
ReportPeriodEndDay, datetime, YES, , , 
ReportDownloadDate, datetime, YES, , , 
ReportPeriod, text, YES, , , 
ReportFilename, text, YES, , , 
marketplace, text, YES, , , 
vendorId, text, YES, , , 
reportYear, bigint(20), YES, MUL, , 
reportMonth, bigint(20), YES, MUL, , 
reportWeek, bigint(20), YES, , , 
reportQuarter, bigint(20), YES, , , 
reportDayOfWeek, bigint(20), YES, , , 
reportDayOfYear, bigint(20), YES, , ,
```

Comment: can you try both code without year function ? year column

Comment: aaargh... that could be it. Let me check. Thx

Comment: I fixed my question. I was already trying without the YEAR() function. Still slow.

Comment: NO CAN You try both query without  year func

Comment: without grouping by year (either through YEAR() or its numeric equivalent), both queries take the same duration now. Interesting.

Comment: I ask for that, if you use year function so on other columns if you youse month func it will be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There **seems to be** some optimization linked to the `YEAR` function, of which `DESCRIBE` knows nothing about (which is logical enough).

The way I would have implemented it is, when the YEAR function is called, if it sees that MONTH is called too, it does additional binning for the month value. Then, that part of the work is already done, and better, than through a CASE on an unrelated field (because the fact that it is called `reportMonth` does not make it related).

Since each year has no more than 12 months, that seems a worthwhile optimization - it won't use too much memory and the potential rewards are appreciable.

If you have a lot of sales per product, you might try a straight grouping by reportYear and reportMonth, and then run the CASE pivoting as a wrapping SELECT. Something like:

```
SELECT 
    ProductTitle,  
    reportYear as `Year`,
    SUM(IF (reportMonth = 1, OrderedRevenue, 0) AS 'Jan',
    ...
    SUM(IF (reportMonth = 12, OrderedRevenue, 0) AS 'Dec',
    SUM(OrderedRevenue) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM (
    SELECT productTitle, 
        reportYear, 
        reportMonth, 
        SUM(OrderedRevenue) AS OrderedRevenue
    FROM
        `sales_diagnostic_summary_orderedrevenuelevel`
        GROUP BY ProductTitle, reportYear, reportMonth
) AS firstGrouping;
```

Very likely, having an index

```
CREATE INDEX myIndex ON
sales_diagnostic_summary_orderedrevenuelevel(ProductTitle, 
   reportYear, reportMonth, OrderedRevenue);
```

while costing something during UPDATE/DELETE/INSERTs, should improve things during this kind of SELECT. You might want to try the DATE version of both double-select and indexing on for size.

Additionally, I don't think there's any reason to store year, month and week as BIGINT. It won't make all that difference either in performance or in storage, but it still smells a bit to me.

Comment: Thanks for giving your thoughts about the initial question. I agree, that makes sense. Also thank you for trying to provide a solution in speeding up things. I created the index as suggested and also tested your query. Unfortunately, it seems that the index is not used (checked with explain, timing is bad also). I checked this with the Group By / Select statement. Any ideas, why this happens?

Comment: That is strange. I'm on the go now, but tonight I'll check it out. It is possible that the optimizer ignores all indexes because it has to do a full table scan anyway. You could try with an index hint (you find examples in the online manual)

Comment: Thanks I will try that. (By the way, I already tried to use FORCE INDEX to no avail).